# A query regarding addition of Absolute Convergence Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given two Absolute Convergent Series $(S_a, S_b)$ that add up to values $(V_0, V_1)$. Can we add or subtract the terms in two series such that:

1. The resultant summation series $S_{ab}$ the relative order of the terms from both the original series is same.
2. We take first $a_0$ terms from series $S_a$, then $b_0$ first terms from series $S_b$; then $a_1$ next terms from series $S_a$, $b_1$ next terms from series $S_b$ and so on..

Would the sum of these kind of series be always equal to $(V_0+V_1)$?

Comment: Absolute convergence implies that you can rearrange and group however you wish, nothing of that will alter the sum.

Comment: Thank you. If the series are conditionally convergent will the above still hold? I think yes as the condition 1. ensures there is no rearranging in each individual series but just 'merging' of series in 2. (I am not sure though)?

Comment: Yes, if you just mix the two series without altering the order in which the terms of each series appear, the resulting series is convergent and its sum is the sum of the values of two constituent series, whether the convergence of the two is conditional or unconditional. If you have absolute convergence, you can do much much more.